# Angularjs - loading data using a service displays the previous page data and not the current one

Tags: angularjs

I'm facing a strange behaviour on my angularjs app.

Basically, I have a service that loads data from a JSON file.

I have two options from this service:

> 1- Load all the data
>
> 2- Load only the data that I need based on the URL

Here's the service code:

```
.service ('myService', ['$http', '$stateParams', '$q', function ($http, $stateParams, $q){
  
  var myService = this;
  var defer = $q.defer();
  
  myService.all = {};
  myService.one = {};
  
  myService.all = function (){
    $http.get('data.json').success(function (res){
      myService.all = res.data;
      defer.resolve(res.data)
    })
    return defer.promise;
  } 
  myService.one = function (urlID){
    $http.get('data.json').success(function(res) {
      angular.forEach(res.data, function(item) {
        console.log (item, parseInt(urlID))
        if (item.id === parseInt(urlID)) {
          console.log("id equality: true")
           myService.oneZone = item;
        } else {console.log("id equality: false")}
        
      });
    });
    return defer.promise
  }
  
  return myService;  
}])
```

and then I call this from my controller:

```
.controller('detailsCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'myService', function($scope, $stateParams, myService) {
    $scope.fromURL = $stateParams.myID
    myService.one($scope.fromURL).then(function(res){
      $scope.onlyOne = myService.oneZone
    })    
}])
```

but the data is displayed in a wrong way.

It is way easier to see it in action here: https://plnkr.co/edit/qBtT5gkVSkYfjbngZVqw?p=preview

To reproduce this, here's what you have to do:

> 1- Once open, click on any button (for example **2**)
>
> 2- the following page will have an empty scope (called onlyOne)
>
> 3- Go back and click on another button (for example **3**)
>
> 4- onlyOne scope is from the first button you pressed (**2**)

why is it doing this?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have to create another promise for myService.one and resolve it.

```
myService.one = function (urlID){
    var defer = $q.defer();
    $http.get('data.json').success(function(res) {
      angular.forEach(res.data, function(item) {
        console.log (item, parseInt(urlID))
        if (item.id === parseInt(urlID)) {
          console.log("id equality: true")
           myService.oneZone = item;
        } else {console.log("id equality: false")}

      });
      defer.resolve(myService.oneZone);
    });
    return defer.promise
  }
```

Here is the working plnkr
https://plnkr.co/edit/TgClvkqUFL7g9KGiug4m?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Promise could be resolved only once and it will always return the same value. If you want to change resolved value you have to create new promise. Besides promise is redundant here, you can simplify code to:

```
myService.all = function (){
    return $http.get('data.json').success(function (res){
      myService.all = res.data;
      return res.data;
    })
}
```

And also .success method is deprecated you should use .then.

With .then it will be probably look like this:

```
myService.all = function (){
    return $http.get('data.json').then(function (res){
      myService.all = res.data.data;
      return res.data.data;
    })
}
```

And one more thing, you can change second function to:

```
myService.one = function (urlID){

    return $http.get('data.json').success(function(res) {
      angular.forEach(res.data, function(item) {
        console.log (item, parseInt(urlID))
        if (item.id === parseInt(urlID)) {
          console.log("id equality: true")
           myService.oneZone = item;
        } else {console.log("id equality: false")}

      });

      return myService.oneZone;
    });

  }
```

Angular will automatically wrap return of .success call into resolved promise;

Comment: Is it a good angular way to do what i'm trying to achieve? I'm also really concerned about memory leaks and something done "the wrong way"

Comment: Thank you. Do you think it is better for performance to use promises or not? What do you usually use for something like this?

Comment: Yes, it looks quite good. Replace all .success with .then and remove redundant promise creation.

Comment: So following your first example, the one that return directly the data, right?

Comment: Yes, remember that methods like .then .success returns promise, which will be resolved with its callback return value and you don't have to create deferred object manually.